# Watchify compile once wrongly and then stops

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, watchify, babelify

I'm on Windows 10 x64, the sources are on a NFS unit.

When i run the script it gives me this:

```
npm run-script watch

> fooprog@1.0.0 watch U:\fooprog
> watchify -v --poll index.js -o ./dist/main.js

471 bytes written to ./dist/main.js (0.01 seconds) at 11:08:08
```

And then it stops.

The "build" script with browserify works like a charm, so it isn't a syntax error inside my Javascript code, i suppose.

My package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "watch": "watchify -v --poll index.js -o ./dist/main.js",
    "build": "browserify index.js -o  ./dist/main.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.3.0",
    "serve": "^11.2.0",
    "uglify-js": "^3.7.2",
    "watchify": "^3.11.1"
  }
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried on my SSD (to exclude NFS problems) and it still doesn't work.